# Processing triggers for man-db. Not building database; man-db/auto-update is not 'true , error

Tags: linux, apt, man

I get this message every time I install a new package in KDE neon via terminal,
Is it normal and I should ignore it or I should fix this?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tree
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/43.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 115 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package tree.
(Reading database ... 280095 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tree_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tree (1.8.0-1) ...
Setting up tree (1.8.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Not building database; man-db/auto-update is not 'true'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning is just that, a warning; it means that `mandb` isn’t run when relevant packages are installed, and the result of that is that the manual page index caches aren’t updated.

The technical reason for the warning is the absence of `/var/lib/man-db/auto-update`. I’m not sure what would cause that. To restore the `man-db` trigger, restore that file:

```
sudo touch /var/lib/man-db/auto-update
```

You will no longer see the warning, and the caches will be updated. You can update the caches yourself:

```
sudo mandb -pq
```

Comment: /var/lib/man-db/auto-update    this file does not exist by default in kde neon but i made it as you said anf fixed the problem

Answer (score 4):

Remove the old mandb index:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/man/*
```

Regenerate it:

```
sudo mandb -c
```

Or connect your device to an AC Power then run (It take a few minutes):

```
sudo systemctl restart man-db.service
```

Then check the `man-db.service`

```
systemctl status man-db.service
```

Comment: It did not help, but thank you for paying attention

Comment: @AriaP74 `sudo pkcon refresh` then `sudo pkcon update`

Answer (score 0):

Check your debconf settings:

```
bash# debconf-show man-db
* man-db/install-setuid: false
  man-db/auto-update: false
```

Change the setting and reconfigure the package:

```bash
echo "set man-db/auto-update true" | sudo debconf-communicate
sudo dpkg-reconfigure man-db
```