# How to run Odoo ERP as daemon on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, rc

I've cloned odoo ERP using git, in directory /home/amr/erp/odoo. Of course I've create a virtual environment and created a startup script "odoo" in /usr/local/etc/rc.d
My concern is not to run the rc script as a root user so I've created a non login user by the following command:

```
pw adduser odoo -d /nonexistent -s /usr/sbin/nologin -c "Odoo ERP"
```

My problem is that when I run the app with "odoo" user it fails but when I run it with "amr" user it starts.
So how I can make the app run with "odoo" user, here my rc script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# PROVIDE: odoo
# REQUIRE: DAEMON
# KEYWORD: shutdown
#

. /etc/rc.subr

name="odoo"
user="odoo"
rcvar="odoo_enable"
odoo_command="/home/amr/erp/odoo/.venv/bin/python /home/amr/erp/odoo/odoo-bin -c /home/amr/erp/odoo/odoo.conf --without-demo=all"

pidfile="/var/run/${name}.pid"
command="/usr/sbin/daemon"                                                                               
command_args="-P ${pidfile} -u ${user} -r -f ${odoo_command}"                                             
                                                                                                          
load_rc_config "${name}"                                                                                 
: "${odoo_enable:=no}"                                                                                   
                                                                                                          
run_rc_command "$1"
```

Comment: You should have a look at your file permissions. `/home/amr/` is likely your home directory with restricted rights. When asking a q "it fails" is too little info. How did it fail? What logs where examined?

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /home/amr
chown -r odoo:odoo erp
```

Then restart the service

Answer (score 0):

i follow [this guide](https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-install-odoo-14-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts) for installing and using odoo as a service.
you may run into some problem while installing `wkhtmltox` due to `man-db`.

take a look at [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626866/processing-triggers-for-man-db-not-building-database-man-db-auto-update-is-not) for resolving that.